# How to create a news like iPhone app that updates weekly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, newsletter

I have created a few small apps for the iPhone so I have some experience.  An organization that I'm in asked me if I could program a weekly newsletter app for them.  I though it would be a good challenge so I agreed.  My question is: how do I get the app to update weekly without the users having to re-download or manually update?  Do I connect to a database or a website?  Can anyone send me the link to a good tutorial?  I wasn't able to find one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very general but I could give you some suggestions.

First, you need to connect to a service that provides you news info. This is needed. The service could send you an xml that you can parse and display, for example in a `UITableView`. XML is not the only solution. You could use also JSON.

For parsing XML I suggest you to read GDataXML, while for JSON JSONKit framework. But there are also other valid framework out there.

Then, to save data it depends on what kind of data you deal with. Here you could find different ways to save your news. Save an XML that contains your news, serialize data and save them in the local filesystem or use Core-Data.

To update your news without user actions, you have to save the last time when the app has downloaded news (for example in `NSUserDefaults`) and each time time the application is "activated" check for that date and update news if necessary.

Out there there are plenty of tutorials on how to (in parenthesis I inserted classes or framework that you could have a look):

- consuming web service on iPhone (ASIHttpRequest - no more supported, `NSURLConnection` class, AFNetworking)
- dealing with XML file/data and theirs parsing (GDataXML, touchXML, etc.)
- dealing with JSON messages (JSONKit, etc.)
- managing documents (`NSFileManager` class)
- using Core-Data
- using Property-List and/or `NSUserDefaults`

First three cover the first step (download). Other three cover the second one (save). Obviously you have not to use all of them. For example a configuration could be:

`NSURLConnection` for service, GDataXML for parsing XML data and Property-List for save data.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to make it a pure web app and update the website weekly.

Your content providers are going to have to do those updates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check: [Adding Newsstand Support to Your App](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/140033-adding-newsstand-support-to-your-app) or [Tutorial: How To Make Your App Work With The Newsstand](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-how-to-make-your-app-work-with-the-newsstand/)